# Image as plane in 2.82

Tags: import

Taking 2.82 for a spin and tried to both 'Add' Images as planes, and 'Import' Images as planes.  Neither option is available.  Will this option be back in when 2.82 has it's final release?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is actually an add-on (shipped with blender) but you have to activate it. Go to Edit > Preferences > Add-ons and look for "Import images as planes"